# How to obtain the direct link to a specific podcast episode in iOS iTunes Store?

Tags: itunes, ios, podcasts, url, itunes-store

My friend, on her iPhone, wants to email me an iTunes Music Store link directly to a specific episode of a podcast. She wants to do this without downloading any 3rd party apps.

Problem is....at least half the time, the link she sends me takes me to a page with many episodes of the given podcast. We just want to link directly to one particular episode so I can be assured I'm gonna' download the right one.

How can this be done?

Comment: You can thank someone for answering by checking the "Accept" button for the best answer. If a better one comes, you can change it later...

Comment: Why does Apple have to make their software so hard to use?

Answer (score 3):

This is how it would work on a Mac; I don't see a way of obtaining a podcast episode URL from within the built-in iTunes iPhone app.

1. In the iTunes app, navigate to the podcast episode and copy the episode link by clicking the little triangle next to "FREE" in the right column:

   [image: How to click triangle]
2. When the link is opened on the Web, you can see what specific episode was linked to in two ways:

   3. It's slightly highlighted in the list (that is, until you start hovering the mouse over that list).
   4. Part of the episode's name is in the URL:

      [image: URL showing name]

Comment: Hi @fanaugen.  Welcome to the site. Sorry to start with a negative, but the OPs question refers to iTunes store on iOS devices, not the iTunes app on Mac/Windows.  It wasn't terribly clear at first when you answered, but I just edited it a little to make it more obvious.

Comment: @stuffe you're right, I overlooked that the question was about iOS. Indeed, I see no way of sharing iTunes links to specific podcast episodes from an iPhone

Comment: It may be worth either editing it, or removing it, before long someone will tag it as "not an answer".  You're good to just turn it around and say something like "From a Mac you can do it like this: .... but there is no way to acheive it from the default iOS apps"

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to obtain the link to a specific episode, either from the iTunes app on iOS where you can browse the store, or from the iOS music app after if has already been downloaded.

Often a direct link to the episode is included in the show notes that are included, but the built in apps have scant support for allowing you to actually view these properly, they just overlay the text (or the top section of it) without giving you a way to interact with it.

To be honest, and I know you specifically asked not to suggest other apps, but given the above should hopefully be a suitable answer in it's own right I will do so anyway.  Try Instacast, it's a far superior app for both downloading/subscribing and actually listening to podcasts.  As you can see if allows full acces to the show notes, you can just click the download link provided to copy the URL, or use the built in sharing functions.

[image]
[image]

While you are at it, you should download the Ask Different Podcast to test it ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in Apple Podcast (iTunes, iPhone, iPad, Apple TV). Sharing an episode will take visitor to the Podcast page instead of the episode page. Apple's current Podcast website still lacks a good way to handle episode level sharing.

I have switched to Pocket Casts and it not only allow episode sharing but also allow the receiver of the shared link to play the episode directly on a browser for free. You can even point the receiver to start a certain position within an episode, like: http://pca.st/H211#t=1m0s

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a simple [javascript tool](http://www.scriptsmashup.com/tools/find-itune-podcast-by-itunes-podcast-page-url-or-itunes-id) to find the iTunes xml rss feed with the Apple api from iTunes podcast page or iTunes ID.

Just paste the Apple store url or product ID.

Answer (score -2):

google the podcast episode by name, it will give you the link.

Comment: Finding the podcast episode is not the problem here. The OP mentioned that half the time, the link he receives points to multiple episodes